# keras fit_generator when you don't know how many steps you'll have

Tags: python, keras

B"H

Is there any way to implement a data generator (either by creating a python generator or by subclassing Sequence) for training data if I don't know in advance how many records I will have in an epoch?

Often times, even if you can't load the entire training set into memory, you still know how may items you will have - for images you can get a file count, or something similar. But sometimes you don't know in advance and it is too expensive to get an exact count - if you have multiple variable length files each with many records, or if you are being fed the training data by an outside source. You may actually have more data at each epoch, by the time the first epoch is done, there may have been more data collected.

So you don't know what number to pass to `steps_per_epoch` or have a real way to implement `__len__`

Currently I am actually working on a *cnn* but this would be more comon by an *lstm*

Comment: You need to define what is an epoch in this case, you either have to measure it (once), or define it in another way (if the data changes for example).

Comment: Thank you for a fast response. At the end when I run out of data (or once I've opened the last file) I do know that the epoch is over. But at that point the `__len__` function has already been read' and i can't just output an EOF or something

Comment: What is the issue with making a script that just computes how many data points there is, you need to compute this only once, and then you can hardcode steps per epoch as samples / batch_size.

Comment: running through (downloading, or loading) each file to count how many samples are in each is too (computationally and financially) expensive. I need to be able to load each resource only once per epoch. So I don't know how many samples there will be in the current epoch until I reach the last resource.

Comment: @Rabbi could you able to solve this issue? if yes please tell me the solution. I am also facing same kind of issue

Comment: Oy! I'm on to the next problem. Now I want to know how to do that in tf.Datasets. Which are basicaly the generators replacement

Comment: @Rabbi so what was your solution? Also if you have solved it can you mark it solved, add your solution, and close it?

Comment: generators are no longer recommended. The new recommended api is datasets